# Unable to POST values by Postman Body form-data using Node API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, postman

I am using the following user controller to insert user using Node Express and MongoDB. When I started to insert values using Postman Body form-data, I am getting the following output as error_message "Invalid request, Invalid 'name' parameter." This error says that I want to insert value for name fiels in the Schema, but I entered the name field and its value in the Body form-data as Key and value, So why this did not work?

**userController.js**

```
const express=require("express");
const router =express.Router();
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const multer = require('multer');
var assert = require('assert');
const User = require('../models/user.model.js');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express(); // define our app using express

// Put these statements before you define any routes.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// POST
exports.create = ("/",(req, res, next) => 
{
    var varName= req.body.name;
    var varUname = req.body.username;
    var varPass = req.body.password;
    var varEmail = req.body.email;

    if(!varName) 
    {
        return res.status(400).send(
            {
                "error_message": "Invalid request, Invalid 'name' parameter.",
                "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
            } 
        );
    }

    // Other Validations are go here...

    const user = new User(
    {
        name: varName, //required
        address: req.body.address, 
        logo: req.body.logo, 
        username: varUname,  //required
        password: varPass,   //required
        phone_number: req.body.phone_number, 
        email: varEmail,  //required
        token_key : token
    });

    // Save Programe in the database
    user.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(
        {
            "error_message": [],
            "results":"User created successfully",
            "status": "Success",
            "token": token
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            error_message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Programe."
        });
    });
});

// GET all
exports.findAll = (req, res) => 
{
    User.find()
    .then(users => {
        res.send(users);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            error_message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving programe."
        });
    });
};
```

UPDATED, Please see my added `server.js` code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');

// Configuring the database
const dbConfig = require('./config/database.config.js');

var multer = require('multer');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url)
.then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...');
    process.exit();
});

app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});

// define a simple route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"message": "Welcome to Agenda APP created by ApptimusTECH."});
});

require('./app/routes/programe.routes.js')(app);
require('./app/routes/user.routes.js')(app);
require('./app/routes/agenda.routes.js')(app);

// listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Change the raw type option in postman to JSON

Comment: Why to use raw option and JSON? I am going to use Front end using react also.

Comment: It's because your app is using JSON body-parsing middleware `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: If I use raw JSON, shall I insert data using react Front End?

Comment: How to change `app.use(bodyParser.json());` to insert data using `form-data` ?

Comment: var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer();
    var app = express();                                                      
    app.use(upload.array()); 
    app.use(express.static('public')); Try This

Comment: Should I put all of this ?

Comment: var upload = multer(); var app = express(); app.use(upload.array()); app.use(express.static('public')); that much only

Comment: Not success, Again also I get the same error

Comment: It only gets value using Params only. Body form-data does not work

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_form_data.htm  check this link @iamCoder

Comment: `server.js` code is added

Comment: @Prashant Gupta, are you here

Comment: Yes bro.. u still Stuck in this ?

Comment: Please see my server.js code

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem? @IamCoder

Answer (score 0):

You can fix up using this way. Please take a look.

```
const path = require('path'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  util = require("util"),
  formidable = require('formidable');
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
      form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        // `file` is the name of the <input> field of type `file`
        console.log("line 98");
        console.log(files);
        console.log("line 100");
        console.log(fields);
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
      });
      form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
      form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        var percent_complete = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected) * 100;
        console.log(percent_complete.toFixed(2));
      });
      form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
         Temporary location of our uploaded file 
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
        /* The file name of the uploaded file */
        var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
        var new_location = '../client/public/media/tickets/';
    
        fs.readFile(temp_path, function(err, data) {
          fs.writeFile(new_location + file_name, data, function(err) {
            fs.unlink(temp_path, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                console.error(err);
              } else {
                console.log("success!");
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
```